# How to draw braces next to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

I have the following tikz graph. How can I draw braces on the left (2cm away) of `Node1`?

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
  ,main node/.style={,fill=white!20,draw,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}]

  \node[main node,scale=0.8] (Node1) {Node 1};
  \node[main node,scale=0.8] (Node2) [right=0.8cm of
   Node1] {Node 2};
    \node[main node,scale=0.8] (Node3) [below=1.5cm of Node1] {Node 3};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(Node1) edge node {} (Node3)
(Node2) edge node {} (Node3)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
  ,main node/.style={,fill=white!20,draw,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}]

  \node[main node,scale=0.8] (Node1) {Node 1};
  \node[main node,scale=0.8] (Node2) [right=0.8cm of
   Node1] {Node 2};
    \node[main node,scale=0.8] (Node3) [below=1.5cm of Node1] {Node 3};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(Node1) edge node {} (Node3)
(Node2) edge node {} (Node3)
;

\draw[-,decorate, decoration={brace, raise=2cm}] (Node3.south west)--(Node1.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can I make the brace wider?

Comment: @kolonel if I understand correctly, adding `amplitude=5pt` to `decoration={...}` should do what you want.